# Inner Form Allignments in CSS: Difficulty with aligning input boxes and text strings

Tags: html, css, forms

So, I'm building a form to collect personal information. Three sections on a line - a text string field name, an `input` box, and a text string  explanation and example, that I want to look like so:

```
      First Name: INPUT BOX eg. Bob, your given name
         Surname: INPUT BOX eg. Smith, your family name
Languages Spoken: INPUT BOX eg. English, French, Chinese,
```

So this is a CSS problem that's beyond me as yet, as CSS is new to me. I'm interested in getting three straight vertical alignments: the colons, the `input` boxes and the eg.s. The far left margin is ragged, as is the far right margin. I want to focus attention on the input boxes in the centre, and position the left and right text strings on either side, one line for each input item. How to go about this? The raw html defaults to a flush left margin with ragged inner alignments.

Thanks for your help,

Bill

Sample html:

```html
<!-- Repeat and customize the 3 line block for each line/input-box/string -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Personal Data Collector </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <form method="post" action="personal_d_collector.py">
      <h3> Personal Data </h3>
      <lable for="f_name"> First Name: </lable>
      <input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name">
      <span> eg. Bob, your given name. </span><br>
      <lable for="l_name"> Surname: </lable>
      <input type="text" id="l_name" name="l_name">
      <span> eg. Smith, your family name. </span><br>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Is there is any design available for your requirement.

Comment: Please specify more precisely

Comment: Please note: For the `<label>` to work properly (i.e. as a label for a field whose name is in the `for` attribute of the `label` tag) it has to be *spelled*  correctly, i.e. not "lable", but "label". This can for example be important for accessibility, but also for semantics in general.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<label for="f_name"> First Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" style="margin-left:200px;">
<span style="float:right;"> eg. Bob, your given name. </span><br>

<label for="l_name"> Surname: </label>
<input type="text" id="l_name" name="l_name" style="margin-left:200px;">
<span style="float:right;"> eg. Smith, your family name. </span><br>
```

This will work, I think to center the input box it's better to first put it inside a div block and then center it to achieve responsiveness.

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <label for="f_name" style="float:left;"> First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" />
  <span style="float:right;"> eg. Bob, your given name. </span><br>
</div>
```

this is another method of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want the input fields to be vertically aligned, you can apply `display: inline-block` to the labels and define a `min-width` for it.

To create some distance between the `input` boxes and the subsequent `span`s, you can apply `padding-left` to them (however, I'd recommend to use classes for this purpose).

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}

form span {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="personal_d_collector.py">

  <h3> Personal Data </h3>

  <label for="f_name"> First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name">
  <span> eg. Bob, your given name. </span><br>

  <label for="l_name"> Surname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="l_name" name="l_name">
  <span> eg. Smith, your family name. </span><br>

</form>
```